# To attack a problem

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, anglicismes

Comment peut-on rendre en français la locution *to attack a problem* ?

Par exemple pour la phrase

> [Eighteen Ways to Attack a Problem.](https://cpb-us-e1.wpmucdn.com/blogs.rice.edu/dist/9/7567/files/2011/04/Bracewell-Problem-Solving.pdf)

je pense à

> Dix-huit façons d’attaquer un problème.
>
> Dix-huit façons de s'attaquer à un problème.
>
> Dix-huit façons d’aborder un problème.

(S')attaquer (à) s'emploie-t-il dans ce contexte ?
Un tel emploi consiste-t-il un anglicisme (ou plutôt un américanisme) ?

Voici les suggestions de lingue (plusieurs sont canadiennes)

https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/attack+a+problem.html

Un lien intéressant pour la phrase originale :

https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Americans-use-the-phrase-attack-the-problem-instead-of-approach-the-problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Les trois expressions sont utilisables.

D'après Google books, ***attaquer un problème*** est attesté en français en 1839 alors que les premières occurrences de *to attack a problem* ne sont trouvées qu'à partir de 1901, il ne peut donc s'agir d'un anglicisme/américanisme.

**S'attaquer à un problème** apparaît à peu près au même moment, mais est resté très rare jusqu'au début du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle où il a peu a peu dépassé la forme non pronominale.

[image]

Le sens peut être perçu comme plus fort qu'aborder, qui est la forme la plus courante des trois proposées, car il sous entend qu'il s'agit d'un combat (au sens figuré).

Le verbe attaquer est cependant parfois proche de débuter comme dans « attaquer son repas » ou « attaquer sa journée » où il n'est pas question d'un combat mais d'une approche vigoureuse et déterminée alors qu'aborder dénote une approche plus prudente.

Answer (score 2):

« S'attaquer » est tout particulièrement désigné pour une utilisation dans ce contexte; on peut rapporter la remarque suivante du TLFi à l'effet d'affirmer cette notion.

> Rem. L'emploi de la forme pronom. à la place de l'actif met l'accent sur la volonté, l'effort opiniâtre du sujet fortement engagé dans l'action (cf. Littré, Sommer 1882).

L'usage figuré du verbe « attaquer » ne relève pas de l'anglicisme. On trouve le terme en 1675 dans les écrits de Madame de Sévigné.

> TLFi : « entreprendre, commencer (un sujet) » (Lettres de Mme de Sévigné[…])

On peut être tenté d'utiliser le verbe « entreprendre » et il est difficile de trouver cela inapproprié vu la définition du dictionnaire qui fait de ce dernier terme un synonyme d'« attaquer »; personnellement, je ne crois pas que ce terme convienne vraiment en raison d'une différence assez substantielle entre la nature de l'objet sur lequel il peut  porter et de celle de l'objet que l'on associe généralement au verbe « attaquer »; cette différence, bien sûr, est le produit de mes perceptions et il m'est difficile d'apporter un support tangible à sa réalité. Les deux termes sont utilisables avec un objet dans les catégories des matières et des sujets qui confrontent une personne à une difficulté, mais à une difficulté moindre, pour ainsi dire une difficulté programmée; lorsque l'on parle d'un problème au sens de « question pas encore résolue » c'est à dire au sens de « problème de recherche » il existe bien certaines directives dont dispose le professionnel pour engager ses effort vers une solution mais elles sont très, très générales; s'attaquer à l'étude de l'histoire, par exemple, consiste assez simplement et pendant assez longtemps à passer en revue des rapports de faits par un historien, l'« attaquant » ne fait pas face à un bien grand inconnu; dans ce cas-là et la multitude de ceux qui lui sont similaires dans le domaine des études « entreprendre » et « attaquer » sont utilisables selon mon opinion comme attaquer « couvre » le domaine d'application d'« entreprendre » (TLFi : Commencer à faire quelque chose qui demande un effort et dont on veut vivement venir à bout). Néanmoins, que l'on considère le mot « problème » selon son sens voisin de par exemple « problème d'algèbre linéaire » c'est à dire « énoncés  fourni en fin de chapitre dans un livre d'étude » et la chose est bien différente : dire ou écrire alors « Cet élève a entrepris plusieurs problèmes mais n'en a vraiment résolu aucun. » me parait parfaitement correct. Si peu complètement convaincante que soit l'information suivante, elle tend à confirmer mes allégations : on ne trouve pas au moyen de la recherche par ngram l'expression « entreprendre un problème » alors que l'expression « attaquer un problème » abonde.

La nuance que l'on trouve dans « aborder » correspond à l'anglais « to approach » (voir votre lien) et donc je pense que si l'on trouve préférable de conserver la nuance choisie, il vaut mieux éviter « aborder ».

Answer (score 1):

Indeed,

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/attack)
>
> Attack
>   4. verb If you attack a job or a problem, you start to deal with it in an **energetic** way.

,

> [Oxford Learner's](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/attack_2)
>
> 5 [transitive] attack something: to deal with
>   something with a lot of **energy and determination**
>   *Let's attack one problem at a time.*

but

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attack)
>
> Attack a : to set to work on

British English might lend a stronger meaning to the expression around the idea of energy and vigor. The emphasis on intent and direction seems to be a constant across British and American though.

Depending on the source and context, you might want to translate to *"s'attaquer à un problème"* or just *"aborder un problème"*. *"Approcher un problème"* is even weaker in French and can denote caution, so it might not be such a good fit.

The paper you linked to may be more tricky. At first sight I would translate it as *"aborder"* since it's an American source and there's nothing particularly virulent about the approach. However, the author uses a belligerent lexicon throughout the text - *plan of attack*, *armory of tools*, *hammering*, *debacle* - therefore *"18 façons de s'attaquer à un problème"* probably reflects the general tone better.